# break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop

Tags: bash, dialog

Any Body Can Help Me About This problem

My bash is

```
#!/bin/bash
#Setup Scripts Project v1.0
#By me
#===============================================



     dialog --backtitle "Setup Scripts " \
     --title "[Main Menu]" \
     --menu "You can use the UP/DOWN arrow keys, Or the number keys 1-9 to choose an option.\n\
    Choose the option" 18 70 8 \
        Setup "Start Setup And Secure this Server" \
        Nginx_Setup "Install Nginx" \
        Anti_MaleWare "Install Anti-MaleWare" \
        Softaculous "Install Softaculous" \
        ModSec "Install ModSecurity" \
        OpsView "Add OpsView Agent" \
        External_Backup "Add This Server To External Backup" \
        Check_Backup "Check Backup Configration" \

menuitem=$(<"${INPUT}")

#Select Option

  case $menuitem in
 Setup) setup;;
 Nginx_Setup) nginx;;
 Anti-MaleWare) anti-maleware;;
 Softaculous) Softaculous;;
 ModSec) modsec;;
 OpsView) opsview;;
 External_Backup) externalbackup;;
 Check_Backup) configbackup;;
     Exit) echo "" ; echo "" ;  break;;
      *) echo "" ; echo "" ; break;;
  esac
```

The Error

```
./main_menu.sh: line 19: : No such file or directory

./main_menu.sh: line 32: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

i need Solve this Error And When i press to any this do this from Other bash script to install

Best Regards,

Comment: Please try to write a proper question, in proper English if you can. Show what you have tried yourself, and try to post the minimum amount of code that still shows the problem. Stack overflow is not a site where you simple dump your code and expect someone else to solve the problem for you, show that you have done some research yourself. You have to improve your question, otherwise it may not be answered or even be removed.

Comment: You also have to learn to believe the error messages from systems software like `bash`, `Bash` isn't kidding, `break` IS only meaningful in a `for`, `while`, or `until` loop. You don't have a loop. Search here for `[bash] while` and you find 1000's of examples. Good luck.

Comment: i'm solve This problem , How can Add option when i Press to nginx Setup , start goin to Anther Bash to setup nginx or any option in Script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-dialog-4175427628/). There is a crazy redirection sequence that swaps stdout and stderr so that the menu can be displayed on the screen, but the answer can be captured with command substitution:

I cleaned up your code a lot, using arrays to hold things.

```
#!/bin/bash

options=( 
    --backtitle "Setup Scripts " 
    --title "[Main Menu]" 
    --menu "You can use the UP/DOWN arrow keys, Or the number keys 1-9 to choose an option.
Choose the option" 18 70 8 
)

choices=(
    Setup           "Start Setup And Secure this Server" 
    Nginx_Setup     "Install Nginx" 
    Anti_MaleWare   "Install Anti-MaleWare" 
    Softaculous     "Install Softaculous" 
    ModSec          "Install ModSecurity" 
    OpsView         "Add OpsView Agent" 
    External_Backup "Add This Server To External Backup" 
    Check_Backup    "Check Backup Configration" 
)

menuitem=$( dialog "${options[@]}" "${choices[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- )

case $menuitem in
    Setup)           setup ;;
    Nginx_Setup)     nginx ;;
    Anti-MaleWare)   anti-maleware ;;
    Softaculous)     Softaculous ;;
    ModSec)          modsec ;;
    OpsView)         opsview ;;
    External_Backup) externalbackup ;;
    Check_Backup)    configbackup ;;
    "")              clear ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you Very much glenn jackman

How We Add option when i Press to nginx Setup , start goin to Anther Bash to setup nginx or any option in Script ?

Comment: You should ask another question with the specifics about what option you want to pass.